# Running Gollum wiki produces NoMethodError at

Tags: github, github-pages, gollum-wiki

Just installed Gollum wiki on Ubuntu server 11.10, and when I go to launch it I get this error:

```
NoMethodError at /
private method `settings' called for Precious::App:Class
file: create.rb location: default_markup line: 44
```

to install it I ran the following:

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
sudo gem install nokogiri
sudo gem install gollum
git init myWiki
cd myWiki
gollum ("sudo gollum" fails with the same error)
```

Ideas?

Note:
If I comment out the offending line the page will load Home.md for editing and then I can save it.  However css styles and page graphics do not load, I just see a poorly formatted html page.

Comment: I just found this link which seems related, maybe I am missing a config.ru setting?
https://github.com/github/gollum/pull/257

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I had Sinatra 1.0 already installed, so that when I installed gollum it did not install the newest version of Sinatra.  Installing Sinatra-1.3.2 fixed the problem.  I now have both Sinatra 1.0 and 1.3.2 installed.

My wiki page's styles now load properly thanks to the Sinatra upgrade, and the NoMethodError message is gone even after uncommenting line 44 of create.rb (though I'm not certain I can credit Sinatra for fixing the NoMethodError message)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup and mine worked fine, although I also installed the markdown gem:

```
gem install redcarpet
```

which might have set the default markup language somehow.  Looking through the code it looks like there are two lines that might help.
in lib/gollum/frontend/app.rb I have this line:

```
set :default_markup, :markdown
```

and in the readme it talks about running your own rake app, and has this line in there as well:

```
Precious::App.set(:default_markup, :markdown) # set your favorite markup language
```

Since I don't know much about rake, I would simply suggest just going in to the app.rb file and manually add that "set :default_markup, :markdown (or whatever language)"